Having trouble wih the mouse and outpot
I want to allow the user to click on his chosen submarine (which are already located:)) and then he clicks another time on the screen and the submarine appers there. For some reason no matter what i click on or where the same submarine (submarine 4) appears and after i move my mouse some of it disappears. In addition I made a loop that should run 5 times, but after one iteration my code is moving on.
proc UseMouse
push ax ; mouse register
push cx ; x cordinates (for future submarine)
push dx ; y cordinates (for future submarine)
push bx
;mov ax,0h
;int 33h
;shr cx,1
wait_for_leftclick:
;mov ax,1h
;int 33h
mov ax,3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 01h
je loop3
jmp wait_for_leftclick ; This begin loop works for sure
loop3:
    
    Tnai1:
    mov ax,3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h
    jne wait_for_leftclick
    mov ah,0Dh
    int 10h
    cmp al, 4
    je Printsub1
    jmp Tnai2
    
    Tnai2:
    mov ax,3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h
    jne wait_for_leftclick
    mov ah,0Dh
    int 10h
    cmp al, 5
    je printsub2
    jmp Tnai3
    
    Tnai3:
    mov ax,3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h
    jne wait_for_leftclick
    mov ah,0Dh
    int 10h
    cmp al, 6
    je printsub3
    jmp printsub4
    
    Tnai4:
    mov ax,3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h
    jne wait_for_leftclick
    mov ah,0Dh
    int 10h
    cmp al, 7
    je Printsub4
    jmp Tnai5
    
    Tnai5:
    mov ax,3h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 01h
    jne wait_for_leftclick
    mov ah,0Dh
    int 10h
    cmp al, 8
    je Printsub5
    jmp Finish

Printsub1:
;shr cx, 1
;mov ax,1h
;int 33h
wait_click1:
mov ax, 3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 01h
jne wait_click1
shr cx, 1
mov [Var1], cx
mov [Var2], dx
push 23
push 40
push 4
push [Var2]
push [Var1]
push offset submarine1
call Sprite_Figure
jmp Finish


printsub2:
;shr cx, 1
;mov ax,1h
;int 33h
wait_click2:
mov ax, 3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 01h
jne wait_click2
shr cx, 1
mov [Var1], cx
mov [Var2], dx
push 23
push 40
push 5
push [Var2]
push [Var1]
push offset submarine2
call Sprite_Figure
jmp Finish

printsub3:
;shr cx, 1
;mov ax,1h
;int 33h
wait_click3:
mov ax, 3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 01h
jne wait_click3
shr cx, 1
mov [Var1], cx
mov [Var2], dx
push 23
push 40
push 6
push [Var2]
push [Var1]
push offset submarine3
call Sprite_Figure
jmp Finish

printsub4:
call setPixel
;shr cx, 1
;mov ax,1h
;int 33h
wait_click4:
mov ax, 3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 01h
jne wait_click4 ; we know for sure this works

shr cx,1
push 23
push 40
push 7
push dx
push cx
push offset submarine4
call Sprite_Figure
jmp Finish


Printsub5:
;shr cx, 1
;mov ax,1h
;int 33h
wait_click5:
mov ax, 3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 01h
jne wait_click5
shr cx, 1
mov [var1], cx
mov [var2], dx
push 23
push 40
push 8
push [Var2]
push [Var1]
push offset submarine5
call Sprite_Figure
jmp Finish

Finish:
pop bx
pop dx
pop cx
pop ax
ret
endp UseMouse

The function
mov ah, 5
timeX5:
dec ah
call UseMouse
cmp ah, 0
jne timeX5

How i call the function
i tried looking yp online for some clues and ask some friends but with no luck. Thanks in advance:)


I want to allow the user to click on his chosen submarine (which are already located:)) and then he clicks another time on the screen and the submarine appers there.


This clearly shows that what you need is a procedure that waits for the left mouse button to be clicked and released before the program continues.
Your present code at wait_for_leftclick: for which you rightfully state that it "works for sure" is followed by code that is not at all waiting for the release of the left mouse button.

All of your Printsub... code uses this shr cx,1 instruction to compensate for how the mouse driver deals with the screen. That's fine of course, but shouldn't you then also use this instruction before reading the pixel from the screen?


; IN () OUT (CX,DX) MOD (AX,BX)
WaitLeftClick:
  mov  ax, 0003h
  int  33h            ; -> BX CX DX
  test bx, 0001h
  jz   WaitLeftClick
WaitLeftClickRelease:
  mov  ax, 0003h
  int  33h            ; -> BX CX DX
  test bx, 0001h
  jnz  WaitLeftClickRelease
  ret

In context:
proc UseMouse
  push ax
  push cx
  push dx
  push bx
  call WaitLeftClick   ; -> CX DX (AX BX)
  shr  cx, 1
  mov  bh, 0
  mov  ah, 0Dh         ; BIOS.ReadPixel
  int  10h             ; -> AL
  cmp  al, 4
  je   Printsub1
  cmp  al, 5
  je   Printsub2
  cmp  al, 6
  je   Printsub3
  cmp  al, 7
  je   Printsub4
  cmp  al, 8
  je   Printsub5
  jmp  Finish
  
  ...
  
Printsub4:
  call setPixel        ; ????
  call WaitLeftClick   ; -> CX DX (AX BX)
  shr  cx, 1
  push 23
  push 40
  push 7
  push dx
  push cx
  push offset submarine4
  call Sprite_Figure
  jmp  Finish
  
  ...
  
Finish:
  pop  bx
  pop  dx
  pop  cx
  pop  ax
  ret
endp UseMouse


In addition I made a loop that should run 5 times, but after one iteration my code is moving on.

Are you sure that the Sprite_Figure procedure returns with those 6 words removed from the stack?

Please respond. If anything isn't clear, leave a comment. And even if everything works ok then either comment, vote and/or accept...
